# React Redux Server side rendered rerendering on client again

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, isomorphic-javascript, server-side-rendering

I created server side rendering with approach described in redux's [official site](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html), everything is great, but on client side it rendering components again, and this is not good I think. I am passing same state from server to `window.__STATE__` variable and passing this to my client side `createStore` method as initial state, but it rerendering again.
Also please write in comments which part of code is needed to you, if so.
I am not providing since it is very similar to official page instructions code and there is no errors, just issue with rerendering, but as I understand it is not connecting to virtual DOM.

Please help me find valid way for handling this task.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example from the ReactGo project: https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo/blob/master/app/client.jsx#L22

They use a function `onUpdate` that has the conditional

```
  if (window.__INITIAL_STATE__ !== null) {
    window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = null;
    return;
  }
```

which prevents a duplicate fetches if `__INITIAL_STATE__` is already defined. Your components rerendering may have something to do with the duplicate fetching.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not understanding what you mean by re-rendering, but it is supposed to "re-render" on the client again. The way isomorphic works is that it renders the HTML on the server, and then the payload includes the initial state as well has the HTML markup - this way the browser "appears" to have faster page load times - since the UI is rendered even before the script is executed. Now once the HTML parsed and the script runs, React internally builds the virtual DOM and then compares it to the server generated DOM and wires up event listeners etc. It does not however, do a full re-render in that no new DOM elements should be created. If for any reason the client run of your React render results in a virtual DOM that is different from the generated server DOM, React will give you a warning.

> "Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the
>   checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server
>   rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the
>   client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which
>   works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering.
>   Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the
>   client or server:"

Comment: Hi, with re-rendering I mean that it is not checking VirtualDOM for diffing, but rendering again whole page. Also react is not giving  me warning, I will check maybe my root component is connected to `redux` and thats why it is re-rendering whole page.